# Laravel Auth::Attempt Assuming Separate Password Table

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I am storing my `User` table, and `Password` table separately. The rationale for this is to prevent accidental leak of the hashed password, should the user accidentally place the `password` parameter in the `$visible` variable of `User`. I'm not sure if this is excessive, or unwarranted, but that is my rationale.

That said, is there anyway to tell `Auth::attempt` that the password is stored in another table, and that a join is required before the hashed password can be accessed?

From the tutorial, the login is simple, assuming that the password field is found in the `User` table

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
    // Blah
}
```

Since I am new to Laravel, I have looked around and could not find anyone using a separate hashed password table in Laravel, so I am not sure if it is supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the hood, `attempt()` method uses one table to get credentials from. You can change `users` table to something else, but you can't keep just passwords in a separate table. So, you'll need to create your own `attempt()` method in this case.

```
public function customAttempt()
{
    // Get password and hashed password.

    // Verify password.
    return password_verify($value, $hashedValue)
}
```